# When starting a website, what languages are recommended for email, open posting, etc...?

Tags: php, html, css

I want to make a site, and I've learned a few languages, but I realize that I may not know the languages needed for the site to do what I want.

- I want a log-in feature that opens areas only to members for example.
- I want a place where people can post even without being logged in like an open message board.

I'm not asking how to do these things, just what languages people recommended for these things. It's only a few key features atm, but I don't plan on it ever being big. I don't know if it'll ever be something. I don't want a forum. I've looked at forums and I don't want that. I want to keep it mostly simple for the moment. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which languages have you learned? You can do this with PHP, HTML and CSS and a webserver.

Comment: This question is doomed to devolve into Yet Another Language Holy War. Just pick something with a lot of documentation (or that you have experience with) and stick with it. Just not PHP ;)

Comment: *Any* language will do for this. These are so high-level, non-specific features that the language absolutely does not matter. Even PHP is fine, contrary to above comment. ;o)

Comment: I only really know Html, css, and some js. I have looked into PHP/MySQL before, but I was hindered a little by being unable to find a way to use an Apache web server for free. Not to use that as an excuse though!

Comment: Use wamp if you're on windows. It's the easiest webserver imho. Also there's MAMP for mac os x, and LAMP for linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically all you need is HTML and CSS, then you can use PHP or Python for most of the things. For database you have a lot of freedom again, you can use noSQL, MySQL, SQLite and a lot's of others.

But it all comes down to what do you know of, and how well do you know that language.

Comment: Only Html, css, and some js. I know the first two rather well. As I mentioned above, I was favoring towards PHP and MySQL, but I've had trouble finding a suitable learning base.

Answer (score 1):

PHP/MySQL for the backend
HTML/CSS for the frontend

Comment: I was thinking that. Thanks for your input.